# Getting System.Security.SecurityException when passing a Typed Dataset via remoting. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: .net, remoting

I'm getting a System.Security.SecurityException after upgrading a production project from .net 2.0 to 4.0. I can pass base types, such as a generic dataset, just fine. However, for a particular typed dataset (XSD), I'm getting:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, ISerParser serParser)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeSoapRequestMessage(Stream inputStream, Header[] h, Boolean bStrictBinding, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SoapServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at DataBridgeWS.Admin.SaveJobData(DataSet jobds)
       at IEDataBridge.Main.SaveJob() in C:\Source\IED\3.2\IEDataBridge\Main.vb:line 2733
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
       GrantedSet=""
       HResult=-2146233078
       Message=Request failed.
       PermissionState=<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>

       RefusedSet=""
       Source=mscorlib
       Url=""
       StackTrace:
            at System.Array.InternalCreate(Void* elementType, Int32 rank, Int32* pLengths, Int32* pLowerBounds)
            at System.Array.CreateInstance(Type elementType, Int32 length)
            at System.Data.DataTable.NewRowArray(Int32 size)
            at System.Data.Index.GetRows(Range range)
            at System.Data.DataColumn.IsNotAllowDBNullViolated()
            at System.Data.DataSet.EnableConstraints()
            at System.Data.DataSet.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
            at System.Data.Merger.MergeDataSet(DataSet source)
            at System.Data.DataSet.Merge(DataSet dataSet, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)
            at DataBridgeJobs.JobData..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) in C:\Source\IED\3.2\DataBridgeJobs\JobData.Designer.vb:line 280

       InnerException:
```

Obviously, the changes in .net 4 security is causing the problem - but after much searching and trying different approaches, I'm a little stuck. I don't want to move to WCF unless absolutely necessary - it's a legacy product.

I am using declarative settings, via the .config files. Both client and server have:

This app is run on intranets, where the backend is hosted in IIS. So it can be (and is) a full trust application).

Here is the relevant portion of the client's exe.config:

```
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="http">
          <serverProviders>
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
          </serverProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```

And here is the server's web.config:

```
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
         <channels>
            <channel ref="http" machineName="localhost">
               <clientProviders>
                  <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
               </clientProviders>
            </channel>
         </channels>
        <service>
            <wellknown mode="SingleCall" type="DataBridgeWS.Admin, DataBridgeWS" objectUri="Admin.rem" />
            <wellknown mode="SingleCall" type="DataBridgeWS.IEVData, DataBridgeWS" objectUri="IEVData.rem" />
        </service>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any  solutions?